# Setup Django with apache using mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, virtualenv

I am trying to setup my django application with apache2 which has been created using virtualenv. Please find my virualhost configuration

```
`WSGIPythonPath  /path/to/environment/folder/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName myapp.example.com 
    DocumentRoot /path/to/mydjangoapp/folder

    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py
    <Directory /path/to/mydjangoapp/folder>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
#       Order allow,deny
#                allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mydjangoapp/folder/wsgi.py
#   <Directory /var/www/>
#       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
#       AllowOverride All
#       Order allow,deny
#       allow from all
#   </Directory>


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel debug

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
`
```

And my wsgi file contain default values which django gives when you create project. I have installed the mod_wsgi. When i am trying to access the domain , as i have used debug level of warning i am getting message as AH00130: File does not exist:  /path/to/mydjangoapp/folder/wsgi.py/ 
with 404 error code

Please let me know is there anything wrong in my virtual host settings or any other issue.

Thanks

Comment: Does that folder exist? Where exactly is the wsgi file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed when i renamed the file wsgi.py to my.wsgi. I am not sure that why this worked for me. as i read on django forums that we need to give the wsgi.py file path but it was not working for me. 
Just wanted to update all that in case if someone is facing the same issue he can try out this thing too :)